# javascript problem on the close button | how i can solve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-6

here javascript is use for creating more then one table field are open multiple time from clicking the one plus button it is working fine now my problem is when i am clicking on the close button then it will be remove but isn't, when i am using in the java script $(this).parent().parent().remove then it isn't work when i am using `$('tbody').remove()` or `$('tbody tr').remove()` or `$('tbody tr td').remove()` then the whole table and it's fields are deleted....please let

[image]me know anyone.. how i can solve it???

```
$('#addRow').on('click', function() {
    addRow();
});

function addRow() {

    var td1 = '<td>' +
        '<label class="control-label">Class / Field :</label>' +
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<input class="form-control" id="idSource" type="text" name="class[]" />' +
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<label class="control-label">University :</label>' +
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<input class="form-control" id="idDestination" type="text" name="university[]" />' +
        '</td>';
    var td2 = '<td>' +
        '<label class="control-label">Institute / Collage Name :</label>' +
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<input class="form-control" id="idSource" type="text" name="institute_name[]" />' +
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<label class="control-label"> Percentage / GPA / CGPA : </label>' +
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<input class="form-control" id="idDestination" type="text" placeholder="00.00" name="per[]"/>' +
        '</td>';
    var td3 = '<td>' +
        '<label class="control-label">Start Date :</label>' +
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<input class="form-control" id="idSource" type="date" name="sdate[]" />' +
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<label class="control-label">End Date:</label>' +
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<input class="form-control" id="idDestination" type="date" name="edate[]" />' +
        '</td>';
    var td4 = '<td><a class="btn btn-danger" id="remove"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a></td>';

    var td5 = '<td>' +
        '<b>&nbsp;</a>' +
        '</td>' +
        ' <td>' +
        '<b>&nbsp;</b>' +
        '</td>' +
        ' <td>' +
        '<b>&nbsp;</b>' +
        '</td>' +
        ' <td style="text-align: right;">' +
        '<b><a class="btn btn-danger" id="remove"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a></b>' +
        '</td>';

    $('tbody').append('<tr>' + td1 + '</tr>' + '<tr>' + td2 + '</tr>' + '<tr>' + td3 + '</tr>' + '<tr>' + td5 + '</tr>');
};

$('tbody').on('click', '#remove', function() {
    var last = $('tbody').length;
    if (last == 1) {
        alert('You Can Not Remove Last');
    } else {
        if (confirm("Do you want to delete this row?")) {
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            $('tbody').remove();
        }
    }
});
```

Blade File

```
 <div class="col-md-12 field-wrapper" id="wrapper">
                        <div class="panel panel-footer">
                        <form id="allInputsFormValidation" class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('create_education')}}" method="post">
                                @csrf
                            <table class="table table-striped col-md-12">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>

                                        <td><b>
                                            <a class="btn btn-success" id="addRow"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td><b>&nbsp;</b></td>
                                        <td><b>&nbsp;</b></td>
                                        <td><b>

                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <div class="form-group column-sizing">
                                <tbody id="tbody">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label class="control-label">Class / Field :</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="class[]" />

                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <label class="control-label">University :</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="university[]" />
                                        </td>                               
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label class="control-label">Institute / Collage Name :</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="institute_name[]" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <label class="control-label">Percentage / GPA / CGPA / SPI :</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="per[]" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label class="control-label">Start Date :</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="date" name="sdate[]" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <label class="control-label">End Date :</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="date" name="edate[]" />
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                     <tr>

                                         <td><b>&nbsp;</b></td>
                                        <td><b>&nbsp;</b></td>
                                        <td><b>&nbsp;</b></td>
                                        <td style="text-align: right;"><b>
                                            <a class="btn btn-danger" id="remove"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a></b>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>

                                </tbody>
                                </div>
                            </table>  
                            <div class="card-footer" style="margin-left: 90%">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-fill">Submit</button>
                            </div>  
                        </form>
                        </div>
                     </div>
```

Comment: Which browser you have to support?

Comment: google chrome..

Comment: Your html structure is very very bad... You have to change it to easily add/remove rows in runtime... And try to use table as little as possible

Comment: why very bad?? for me it is easy but i have problem to make a javascript same structure but only some change and it is working condition so why it is not working???

Comment: first of all, fix your HTML code, you shouldn't have duplicate id's! stop with the `'...' + '...'` just use blackslack and add all your code there, it will be so much more readable! The easiest way is to have a counter, then assign it to each `td`, maybe like: `<td data-block="${total_bocks}">` and in the button, add a `<a class="btn btn-danger" class="btn-remove" data-block="${total_bocks}">...` then attach a `.btn-remove` event on click, read the `data-block` and delete all td's with that `$("td[data-block=' + id + ']).remove()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Here's the new approach, I hope it will fit your needs.

### Press "Run code snippet" button below

```js
$('#data').on('click', '.remove-record', ({currentTarget: elRemove}) => {
  var isLastRecord = $('.data-record').length === 1;
  if (isLastRecord) {
    alert('You Can Not Remove Last');
  } else if (confirm('Do you want to delete this row?')) {
    $(elRemove).closest('.data-record').remove();
  }
});

$('#add-new-record').on('click', () => $('#data').append(`
  <table class="data-record table table-striped col-md-12">
    <tr>
      <td><label class="control-label">Class / Field :</label></td>
      <td><input class="form-control" id="idSource" type="text" name="class[]" /></td>
      <td><label class="control-label">University :</label></td>
      <td><input class="form-control" id="idDestination" type="text" name="university[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label class="control-label">Institute / Collage Name :</label></td>
      <td><input class="form-control" id="idSource" type="text" name="institute_name[]" /></td>
      <td><label class="control-label"> Percentage / GPA / CGPA : </label></td>
      <td><input class="form-control" id="idDestination" type="text" placeholder="00.00" name="per[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label class="control-label">Start Date :</label></td>
      <td><input class="form-control" id="idSource" type="date" name="sdate[]" /></td>
      <td><label class="control-label">End Date:</label></td>
      <td><input class="form-control" id="idDestination" type="date" name="edate[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>&nbsp;</a></td>
      <td><b>&nbsp;</b></td>
      <td><b>&nbsp;</b></td>
      <td style="text-align: right;"><b><a class="remove-record btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a></b>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
`));
```

```html
<!-- required modules -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- add new row button -->
<div>
  <button class="btn btn-success" id="add-new-record">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
  </button>
</div>

<!-- here goes data -->
<div id="data"></div>
```

---

### Thoughts and recommendations

As you can see now you don't have initial empty record (row) - I think it's better for `DRY` and `KISS` principles.

DRY stand for "Don't Repeat Yourself"
KISS for "Keep It Super Simple" or "Keep It Simple Stupid" - you can choose what you like most )

Comment: if you're willing to do all that work: `id="remove"` -> duplicated html identifier... maybe change to `class="btn-remove"` ? 

Comment: @java-man-script    i am using your code but when i run your code then it is shown error before i am using it..errors like data missing..

Comment: Checked it out - try to press the "Run code snippet" button

Comment: it is run but error is same when i click plus button for more fields.. i put first field is default...

Comment: It's working in live example that I provided - you should try to figure out what differences you have with this live example. In order to help you - can you provide the error which is appearing?